# I'm using OData4j for Android,I can't get the entities

Tags: java, odata4j

This is my code:

```
package com.example.toggleDemo;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumer;
import org.odata4j.core.OEntity;
import org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity  extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, GetExpenseReports()));
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }

    ArrayList<String> GetExpenseReports()
    {
        ArrayList<String> listUI = new ArrayList<String>();
        ODataConsumer c = ODataJerseyConsumer.create("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/");
        List<OEntity> listCategories= (List<OEntity>) c.getEntities("Categories");
        for(OEntity category : listCategories) {
            listUI.add(String.format("%s-%s", category.getProperty("CategoryID").getValue().toString(), category.getProperty("CategoryName").getValue().toString()));
        }
        return  listUI;
    }
}
```

When run in the emulator,it's error :
08-28 17:30:05.793: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate
        at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer.(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:22)
        at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer.(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:14)
        at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer$Builder.build(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:93)
        at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer.create(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:115)
        at com.example.toggleDemo.MainActivity.GetExpenseReports(MainActivity.java:38)
        at com.example.toggleDemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and I can't use ODataConsumer.create(..) and I can't use the code: List<OEntity> listCategories= c.getEntities("Categories").execute().toList();

the complie report "Cannot resolve method 'toList()'.But I see the demo code of OData4j that using 'toList()',Why do I can't use?

Comment: Though the tracing,I found in findEdmEntitySet() of EdmDataServices.java, I can't get the this.schemas.The this.schemas is null.

Answer (score 0):

try this 
it worked for me 
ArrayList listUI = new ArrayList();
        ODataConsumer c = ODataJerseyConsumer.create("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/");
        OQueryRequest catagories = c.getEntities("Categories");

```
    Enumerable<OEntity> enumCatagory = catagories.execute();
    OEntity category = enumCatagory.first();
    System.out.println(enumCatagory.count());
    String str = String.format("%s-%s", category.getProperty("CategoryID").getValue().toString(), category.getProperty("CategoryName").getValue().toString());
    System.out.println(str);
```